# Change Parent Account

Tags: data-loader, account

Have one question, i have more then 10000 Accounts and all of them have configure the parent account.now here i just want to change the Parent account for all of them.

I have seen that parent account is a standard field and Hierarchy is the data type.

So is there any way to change the parent account for all of the accounts.

thanks for your support in advance

Comment: you want to change the parent accounts of all records with the same account?

Comment: yes i want to change the parent accounts of all records with same account

Comment: i have not checked over there right now i am going over there

Answer (score 4):

You can just fill in the AccountId of the parent you want in the **ParentId** field using **Data Loader**.

You can also find more info [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gmkSAAQ).

Comment: oki i will going over there in data loader and check if is there ParentId or not and let u know